# Python 3 - Writing Multiple API Queries to Single JSON file

Tags: python, python-requests

I am currently working an API tool written in Python 3 that queries multiple urls to get API data and then writes the results to a single .JSON file. I have managed to get this to work but it appears that the script runs but only the last API request is saved.

What I want is for each request to have its own row. This is what I've done so far from looking at previous questions but it still only saves the last API request. Please could you advise what I'm doing wrong? Apologies that this may look simple but I completely new to Python.

Best,
Stig0501

```
import requests
import json

urls = ["https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random", 
    "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random"]

final_data = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36'}

for url in URLs:
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
final_data.update(data)

with open ('output.json', 'w') as f:
   for fd in final_data:
     json.dump(fd, f)
f.write('\n')
```

Comment: If each `data` has the same keys, then the entries in `final_data` will be overwritten with each request.

Comment: Change `final_data` to be a `list`.

Comment: Change `final_data` to be a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the final_data a list

```
final_data = []
```

And append the request data

```
final_data.append(data)
```

The file will contain all requests.

For the each request being on its own row:

```
for fd in final_data:
    json.dump(fd, f)
    f.write("\n")
```

Comment: Hi Hakran, thank you for your quick response. I have tried this and now I get all of the data but it still is on the same row. I have updated my code in the question to what it is like now

Comment: You could put a new line after the `json.dump(fd, f)`  with `f.write("\n")`

Comment: After updating your code, the question description does not explain what is going on in your code. `but only the last API request is saved` is not correct anymore.

Comment: This also should give a syntax error `final_data.update(data)` List does not have an update function.